# Get Formatted Text of Linked Document

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

In order to get text of linked document and insert it to the documentation I used the `element.GetLinkedDocument()` method.

However, I got RTF characters within the text. 
Therefore, I used the `Repository.GetFormatFromField()` method to return it to simple text.

What I would like now is to get the linked document text formatted just as it looks like from within EA- without RTF characters but formatted.
Any ideas?

```
string linkedDocumentText = Repository.GetFormatFromField("TXT", Repository.GetFieldFromFormat("RTF", element.GetLinkedDocument()));        
Document.Instance().InsertText("\n" + linkedDocumentText + "\n", "Normal");
```

Comment: Does that make sense? If you want the RTF-format then fetch it as such and insert it as RTF in your document.

Comment: To clarify: do you want to retain paragraph and page breaks, bold typeface, etc? And what do you want to do with it -- place it in an EA Notes field, or write it into a document? (Or even an HTML document?)

Comment: @Uffe, I would like to insert the text to a Word document.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, I would like the text formatted, but I get it like : 
`{\rtf1\ansi\deflang3081\ftnbj\uc1\deff0
{\fonttbl{\f0 \fswiss Arial;}{\f1 \froman Times New Roman;}{\f2 \fswiss \fcharset177 Arial (Hebrew);}{\f3 \fswiss \fcharset0 Arial (Hebrew);}{\f4 \fswiss \fcharset177 Arial;}{\f5 \fswiss \fcharset0 David;}{\f6 \fswiss \fcharset177 David;}{\f7 \froman \fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f8`    Any ideas?

Comment: This is RTF. No idea what your Document object can do with RTF. Eventually you need some other class to handle RTF if it can't cope with it.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, What do you mean? This what I get from `element.GetLinkedDocument();`

Comment: Yes. And that is RTF. What is it that you don't understand?